# Is this some kind of Perron-Frobenius theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition

If one has a matrix $A$ whose entries are all $\geq 0$ (or $>0$) then there apparently exists a diagonal matrix $D > 0$ (i.e all the diagonal entries are positive) and a constant $\alpha >0$ such that $D^{-1} A D (id) = \alpha (id)$ where $(id)$ is a column vector of all $1$s.

- Is this above some restatement of the standard Perron-Frobenius theorem? Can someone kindly explain the equivalence?

---

It would help if you could reference to sections in the book by Horn and Johnson - because thats the book that I have with me.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect if $A$ is merely nonnegative. The Perron-Frobenius theorem states (among *many, many* things) that if $A\ge0$, it has a *nonnegative* eigenvector corresponding to its spectral radius $\rho(A)$. It does not guarantee that this eigenvector is positive. Nor does it guarantee that $\rho(A)$ is positive. For example, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}.
$$
If $D^{-1}AD\mathbf1=\alpha\mathbf1$ for some positive diagonal matrix $D$ and some $\alpha>0$, then $A(D\mathbf1)=\alpha D\mathbf1$. In other words, $Av=\alpha v\ne0$ for some positive vector $v$. But this is clearly impossibly because by construction, the last entry of $Av$ must be zero. In fact, all eigenvalues of $A$ are zero, so $A$ does not have any positive eigenvalue $\alpha$, not to say any eigenvector (positive or not) for such $\alpha$.

The statement in your question is correct, however, when $A>0$. The Perron-Frobenius theorem states (again, among many, many things) that if $A>0$, $A$ has a positive eigenvector $v$ corresponding to its spectral radius $\rho(A)$. Since both $A$ and $v$ are positive, it follows that $\rho(A)>0$. So, if we set $\alpha=\rho(A)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(v)$, then $D$ is invertible and $D^{-1}AD\mathbf1=\alpha\mathbf1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A>0$:

From Frobenius-Perron to this claim: Choose $D$ s.t. $D(id)$ is the eigenvector of $A$ and $\alpha$ the eigenvalue given by Frobenius-Perron. In other words the diagonal of $D$ is the positive eigenvector of $A$.

About the other direction: there are so many statements in F-B...

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand in this answer, the most glaring one is that $A$ is not necessarily irreducible, so you can't apply use the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: OK. I assumed the entries to be $> 0$.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm unfamiliar with this version of the theorem, but I see on wikipedia that it is true.

Comment: @ploosu2 Thanks! Can you may be state as to what is the definition of "irreducible" you are using? (what has that got to do with all entries in the matrix being positive) And what is the Perron-Frobenius statement that you have in mind?

Comment: @guest For irreducible: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html For Perron-Frobenius, basically the one that is in wikipedia for positive matrices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: @guest And about the positivity of the matrix: a positive matrix is clearly irreducible since there are no zeros (it can't be permuted to block upper-triangular form).

Comment: @ploosu2 But I am considering situations where some entries can be 0